# Windows phone - Counting number of times phone has been turned on/off

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Just checking if its possible on WinPhone 8.1, to log a daily count of power on/off and screen locked/unlocked events. Ideally I'd like to maintain a log with timestamps but counts will do too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible in Windows Phone.